# Powershell: Import CSV with specific headers, and export with different headers

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a source CSV with no headers that I'm importing, in order to split into multiple CSV's. I'm using `Import-CSV` with the `-Headers` flag to be able to organize the data as needed. However, I'm at a bit of a loss for how to change the headers when exporting to the new CSV. Code is below. What outputs from this is the headers giving during the `Import-CSV` call.

```
# Set variables
$csv_source = "\\firmname\dfs1\CMWS\CM.TXT"
$custom1_file = "C:\WSGEN\custom1.csv"
$custom2_file = "C:\WSGEN\custom2.csv"

#Import source CSV
$csv_orig_data = Import-CSV -Path $csv_source -Header 'C1ALIAS','C1DESCRIPT','C2ALIAS','C2DESCRIPT'

# Grab C1 columns
$c1data = $csv_orig_data | Select-Object C1ALIAS, C1DESCRIPT
$c1data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ENABLED" -Value "Y"
$c1data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HIPAA" -Value "N"
$c1data | Export-CSV -Path $custom1_file -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|'

# Grab C2 columns
$c2data = $csv_orig_data | Select-Object C2ALIAS, C2DESCRIPT, C1ALIAS
$c2data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ENABLED" -Value "Y"
$c2data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HIPAA" -Value "N"
$c1data | Export-CSV -Path $custom2_file -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Why not use the *export* header names when calling ```Import-Csv``` so the properties have the correct names for exporting already? Alternatively you can use calculated properties (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) in ```Select-Object``` to "rename" the properties to the desired names - you could even use that instead of the ```Add-Member``` calls as well...

Comment: Since I'm pulling the data from one source, I wanted the headers to reflect what I'm pulling. The 2nd CSV will need similarly named headers, so it would confuse the issue if I assign the correct final headers on the import.

Comment: In that case, try generating a new dataset for each export by passing the original imported data into ```Select-Object``` (like you're already doing) and using calculated properties to re-shape the output as appropriate ready for export - see the link in my previous comment for details...

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with the below

```
# Set variables
$csv_source = "\\firmname\dfs1\CMWS\CM.TXT"
$custom1_file = "C:\WSGEN\custom1.csv"
$custom2_file = "C:\WSGEN\custom2.csv"

#Import source CSV
$csv_orig_data = Import-CSV -Path $csv_source -Header 'C1ALIAS','C1DESCRIPT','C2ALIAS','C2DESCRIPT'

# Grab C1 columns and export to new CSV
$c1data = $csv_orig_data | Select-Object C1ALIAS, C1DESCRIPT | Sort-Object * -Unique
$c1data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ENABLED" -Value "Y"
$c1data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HIPAA" -Value "N"
$c1data | Select-Object @{Name="ID";Expression={$_.C1ALIAS}}, @{Name="DESCRIPTION";Expression={$_.C1DESCRIPT}}, @{Name="ENABLED";Expression={$_.ENABLED}}, @{Name="HIPAA";Expression={$_.HIPAA}} | Export-CSV -Path $custom1_file -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|'

# Grab C2 columns and export to new CSV
$c2data = $csv_orig_data | Select-Object C2ALIAS, C2DESCRIPT, C1ALIAS
$c2data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ENABLED" -Value "Y"
$c2data | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "HIPAA" -Value "N"
$c2data | Select-Object @{Name="ID";Expression={$_.C2ALIAS}}, @{Name="DESCRIPTION";Expression={$_.C2DESCRIPT}}, @{Name="ENABLED";Expression={$_.ENABLED}}, @{Name="HIPAA";Expression={$_.HIPAA}}, @{Name="PARENTID";Expression={$_.C1ALIAS}} | Export-CSV -Path $custom2_file -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter '|'
```